# iPod Classic interface

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod

I am currently developing an interface for iPhone that mimics the iPod Classic, click wheel and all. I know that Apple will not accept this for the App Store as they explicitly say so, but I was looking through their copyrights and such and was wondering if there is anything stopping me from distributing it in some other way such as Cydia for jailbroken users. Would this be a legal thing to do?

Comment: I am not sure if this is programming related. Its more of a legal matter.

Comment: You may have better luck over at [`apple.SE`](http://apple.stackexchange.com) but this question is probably off-topic there as well. Best ask a lawyer.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't really think of a good place to ask so I thought since I was programming it this was as good of a place as any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's completely legal to distribute apps through Cydia - Jailbreaking was ruled legal in the US a couple of years ago.

It does violate the warranty on the phone however, so relatively few iPhone owners do it, and if you are hoping to sell your app, be warned that Jailbroken iPhones have no copy protection, so a lot of Jailbreakers pirate their software.

If you don't mind targeting a very tiny market with a disproportionate percentage of pirated-to-legimate apps, then go for it!

In terms of the legality of copying the iPod interface, Apple have been trying and failing to sue device manufacturers for copying their designs for years, so I would't worry too much. I'd avoid using the word "iPod" anywhere in your design though as that's a trademark and will be much better protected by law.

Comment: Of course, for a small software developer, even the ordeal of being sued by Apple could bankrupt you or pose a serious complication to your business model. (Talking about the iPod interface, not jailbreaking. That's totally legal.)

Comment: I don't believe a company like Apple would bother to sue a small developer over an app like this. More likely is that they would send a cease and desist letter and then you would just change or remove it. Even more likely is that they would simply ignore it.

Comment: I know that jailbreaking is now completely legal so I was mainly asking what you answered with the second part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to distribute it through Cydia, legality shouldn't be a problem. Cydia is a third party distribution platform, so often things less that illegal are allowed.

For example, install0us gives free copies of paid applications, which is obviously legal. However they haven't faced any legal action due to Cydia not exactly being too strict or regulative.

Don't take me word on this though, because I'm not a 100% sure.

Comment: How is providing free copies of pirated software "obviously legal"?